# Converting a string (user input) into an integer using lists and if statements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I had a school project in which I need to take a user input as an integer between 1-12 (representing the months of the year), and the age of the user, and do a math equation to produce a number that will spit out the age and birth month of the user (yes I know this is redundant but I have to do the math equation and not spit out the user inputs). Me being that one kid who wants an 100% tried to make it so that the user can input the month by string e.g(Jan = 1) using lists and if statements. The code bellow isn't working as whenever a user inputs something if statement doesn't change the birthNum variable. So please help me as i have tried almost everything and nothing works, but I feel as if I am so close to getting it to work.

Here is the code for turning the user input (string) into a integer:

```
birthNum = 0

listOfMonths = ["January", "Jan", "january", "jan", "1", "Febuary", "Feb", "febuary", "feb", "2", "March", "Mar", "march", "mar", "3", "April", "Apr", "april", "apr", "4", "May", "may", "5", "June", "Jun", "june", "jun", "6", "July", "Jul", "july", "jul", "7", "August", "Aug", "august", "aug", "8", "September", "Sept", "september", "sept", "9", "October", "Oct", "october", "oct", "10", "November", "Nov", "november", "nov", "11", "December", "Dec", "december", "dec", "12"]

janList = ["January", "Jan", "january", "jan", "1"]

febList = ["Febuary", "Feb", "febuary", "feb", "2"]

marList = ["March", "Mar", "march", "mar", "3"]

aprList = ["April", "Apr", "april", "apr", "4"]

mayList = ["May", "may", "5"]

junList = ["June", "Jun", "june", "jun", "6"]

julList = ["Jul", "july", "jul", "7"]

augList = ["September", "Sept", "september", "sept", "9"]

septList = ["September", "Sept", "september", "sept", "9"]

octList = ["October", "Oct", "october", "oct", "10"]

novList = ["November", "Nov", "november", "nov", "11"]

decList = ["December", "Dec", "december", "dec", "12"]

(birthMonthInput) = input("Please put in your birth month: ")


if (birthMonthInput == (janList)):
    birthNum = int(1)

if (birthMonthInput == (febList)):
    birthNum = int(2)

if (birthMonthInput == (marList)):
    birthNum = int(3)

if (birthMonthInput == (aprList)):
    birthNum = int(4)

if (birthMonthInput == (mayList)):
    birthNum = int(5)

if (birthMonthInput == (junList)):
    birthNum = int(6)

if (birthMonthInput == (julList)):
    birthNum = int(7)

if (birthMonthInput == (augList)):
    birthNum = int(8)

if (birthMonthInput == (septList)):
    birthNum = int(9)

if (birthMonthInput == (octList)):
    birthNum = int(10)

if (birthMonthInput == (novList)):
    birthNum = int(11)

if (birthMonthInput == (decList)):
    birthNum = int(12)

print (birthNum)
```

Comment: 1st use only lowercase in your list then use `input("enter month: ").lower()` when gathering input. 2nd create a dictionary of the lists and use a for loop to test the months: `months={1:janList,2:febList} #ect` and
     `for month in months:`
       `if birthMonthInput in months[month]:`
         `# month is correct and number is month (already in int form)`

Comment: FebRuary misses an *r*, August is wrong. Standardizing the case before comparison (e.g. by *lower* method of string) would help to simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is checking whether a string evaluates to a list. What you're looking for is the `in` keywork - i.e.

```
if birthMonthInput in augList:
```

That said, there's plenty of other problems in your code.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the constructive criticism (still pretty new at python) and fixing my if statements, you have no idea how much this helped me. Thx again

Answer (score 1):

Using lists for this is highly unperformant. Your solution would require about 5 * 12 lookups for getting the value associated with a String.

A way faster data structure that can do this use case in `O(1)` is a dict.
Try to format your code like this:

```
dic = {
   "Jan": 1,
   "January": 1,
   "Feb": 2 # and so on
}
```

Then you can get your solution by simply doing:

```
birthNum = dict[birthMonthInput]
```

Read [python data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for a good overview. Dictionaries are section 5.5

Comment: How much more complex is a fuzzy match on the dict keys? :p

Comment: wouldn't use a fuzzy match here. You could just use lowercase and substring [0:3]. This would save memory, but should be slower and less flexible.

Comment: But that won't handle a typo, so you make it run the fuzz when it doesn't match and offer the suggestion of what you could have meant. :)

Comment: your dict needs `comma`s

Comment: And you shouldn't use `dict` due to clash with built-in `dict`

Comment: Thanks with the fix, will be looking into dictionaries :).

Comment: and avoid `CamelCase` variables these should be reserved for classes.

Comment: Thanks, have done too much ruby recently xD i'll keep the variables as they are like this in the question. To be really correct class names should be `PascalCase` (upper camelcase)